# Why would I ever want a static NodeList/HTMLCollection over a "live" NodeList if I don't need the granularity of CSS Selectors in the resulting list?

Tags: javascript, dom, nodelist, selectors-api

I generally hear that because live NodeLists are "bad" [(see this Zakas article)](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/09/28/why-is-getelementsbytagname-faster-that-queryselectorall/) and that informed the decision for `querySelectorAll` to return a static `HTMLCollection`. Why do people think live NodeLists are a bad thing? Code examples would probably help me understand this best.

If, whenever I care to use the value of a cached collection of Nodes for any computation that collection happens to not be a stale snapshot, I can't really see that as a "bad" thing.

I understand exactly how much more useful it is to select elements with a CSS Selector string, but if I can only reliably run code against that collection right after acquiring it, it seems to be quite a bit less useful than a live `NodeList`.

Comment: Check out [NodeList.js](https://github.com/eorroe/NodeList.js)

Answer (score 9):

Live nodelists are not bad, but their behaviour can be confusing if you're not used to it. Especially if you think of them as arrays (they're not arrays)

Consider a classic example of doubling the number of divs in a page. Here are three attempts at this:

```
// Example 1 (doesn't work)
for(var i = 0; i < document.querySelectorAll("div").length ; i++){
    document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("div"));
}

// Example 2 (works)
var divs = document.querySelectorAll("div");
for(var i = 0; i < divs.length ; i++){
    document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("div"));
}

// Example 3 (doesn't work)
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++){
    document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("div"));
}
```

Example 1 is clearly an infinite loop. Each iteration, it rechecks the number of divs in the page.

Example 2 works as expected because the nodelist is already cached (of course it would be better to simply cache the length).

Example 3 looks like example 2. Many people would expect it to work the same way, as the nodelist is cached. But as the nodelist is live, it is actually another infinite loop. This catches some people out.

Also, if a function returns a static nodelist, you can requery the DOM each time you need it. This is arguably simpler than converting your live list to static.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. First, I was heretofore unaware of any classic examples of div doubling. What is the practical use case? Second, if I happen to find this 'behaviour' intelligible, which incidentally I do; I remain unenlightened as to why a static NodeList would ever be preferable. Third, writing a function to return the static NodeList could prove expensive in certain cases, and IMHO still begs the question,...Why?

Comment: @bodine
1: A use case might be adding a reference section to the bottom of a page, containing all the links in a page (ie. a copy of all the anchor elements). If you weren't careful, you could end up with an infinite loop.
2: It usually isn't.
3: True.

The main reason that a live list is considered dangerous is that many people don't understand them.

Answer (score 0):

**live** NodeList are quicker to retrieve, so they are **more performant**
**static** NodeList is ***less*** performant.

[see the difference](http://jsperf.com/queryselector-vs-getelementbyid-pure) by eg. between `querySelector`(querySelectorAll) and `getElementById`

In the same conditions `getElementsByTagName` is better to use than `querySelectorAll`...

At least that I read from the Microsoft official training guide "Programming in HTML5 with JavaScript and CSS3"...